# What is the condition for a signal to be invertible?

Tags: signal, system

I have seen, y(t) = x(t+5) is invertible, with inverse being y(t-5).
But y(t) = sin(5t) is not invertible, why?

What is the test condition to see whether a signal has an inverse or not?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a system is invertible, if there is a distinct output for every distinct input, meaning that the mapping of input points (in your case *t*) to the output (in your case *y*) is one-to-one. The function or system like $$y(t) = sin(5t)$$
is not invertible since there are tons of input points which result in the same output point $$(e.g. sin(0)=sin(5pi/5)=sin(5(2pi/5))=sin(5(kpi/5))=0 )$$.

Comment: Yes quite right, but do not forget to specify **domain** i.e. where we look at the function, the subset we are taking care of. E.g. sinus is invertible if you consider its restriction between -pi/2 and +pi/2. Infact most calcualtors do have sin-1 key.

Comment: good point, if we restrict input domain (as you pointed out in this case -pi/2 to pi/2) the mapping would be revertible.

Answer (score 0):

An invertible function is a function \$y(x)\$ that has a unique inverse \$x(y)\$. For this to be the case the function needs to be injective:

[image: injective]

You can see that you can easily invert each element. If the function is surjective:

[image: surjective]

Element C cannot be inverted, because it needs to be mapped to two distinct values.